# How can i get dict key if i have a number in range

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, range

```py
import random
lesson_number = {
    1: [0, 560],
    2: [561, 615],
    3: [616, 670],
    4: [671, 720],
    5: [721, 830],
    6: [831, 880],
    7: [881, 930],
    8: [931, 1439]
}
w = random.randint(0,1439)
```

Now i need so any number in range will return key of that range, for example 258 will return 1, 616 will return 3 and 1234 will return 8. Any ideas how to do that? It isn't matter, u can change lesson_number dictionary but u saw my goal. I'll be happy for any comments

Comment: You'd need to adjust your data structure, but [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html). See the `grade` example, it is almost exactly parallel to what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple method:

```
import random
lesson_number = {
    1: [0, 560],
    2: [561, 615],
    3: [616, 670],
    4: [671, 720],
    5: [721, 830],
    6: [831, 880],
    7: [881, 930],
    8: [931, 1439]
}
w = random.randint(0,1439)

# print(ran)

def lesson_no(w, index = lesson_number):
    for i, ran in index.items():
        if w in range(ran[0], ran[1]+1):
            return i
    return "Invalid Input"

print(lesson_no(w)) # Function call

print(lesson_no(616)) # Example

# Out: 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `bisect`:

```
a = [0,560,615,670,720, 830, 880, 930, 1439]

import bisect

def map_val(n):
    index = bisect.bisect_left(a, n)
    return index
print(map_val(w))
```

---

if `w: 258`

```
out: 1
```

---

if `w: 616`

```
out: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

One line solution

```
list(lesson_number.keys())[list(lesson_number.values()).index([x for x in list(lesson_number.values()) if w >= x[0] and w <= x[1]][0])]
```

To explain further, first get the value that satisfies the condition:

```
k = [x for x in list(lesson_number.values()) if w >= x[0] and w <= x[1]][0]
```

Then extract the key of that value:

```
list(lesson_number.keys())[list(lesson_number.values()).index(k)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries don't work like that. As you know dictionaries have key-value pairs that go one way. You put the key and the value is returned, not the other way around. If you'd like to search a key by a value I would consider switching them around, other wise there's no point in using a dict since you'd have to search the values one by one witch would take linear time. Pythons implementation of a dict uses a 1-1 hash function, if you want a dict that has a specific n-1 hash function then you'd need to implement your own or use a different data structure that fits your needs.